# Reading from SerialPort I/O Timer c# Visual Studios 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer, event-handling, serial-port

I am currently working on a project where I am reading data off a custom made PCB using the **SerialPort** library in Visual Studios 2010 c#.

I am currently attempting to read a certain type of data given to me as bytes of data from the device via button click, and wait five seconds before timing out if no response from device.

However for some reason the timer is being glitchy and often times expires before five seconds have elapsed, thus stopping valid data from being stored. Below is my code used, can someone point out my flaw? I suspect the event timer function from **System.Windows.Forms.Timer** that I use is incorrect.

**Button Click**

```
    bool flag = false;
    private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string command = "*data#";//make string command to send
        sendCommand(command);
        flag = true;
        gui.Timer.Interval = timerlength;
        gui.Timer.Enabled = true;
        gui.Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);


    }
```

**Timer Event Handler**

```
    private void readVarsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (flag == true)
        {
            flag = false;//set flag low
            print("Data Timer Expired, Run Command Again.");
            gui.Timer.Stop();//stop timer
            gui.Timer.Enabled = false; //event over
            timerlength = 5000;//reset timer

        }
    }
```

**Serial Port reading data in, please assume settings for Serial Port is correct, as any transmission or received data not using a timer works just fine.**

```
            if (flag == true)
            {
              //code to read data in, and parse to display in text boxes correct 
              flag = false; 
            }
```

**Other important notes:**

- I have three types of data i can expect from the device, so i use if/else's with flags set by a corresponding button. Hence the global declaration of the 'flag' variable.
- I have not detected issues with the serialport getting trash data that could throw me off, I have run and analyzed the data enough to know i get the correct expected data.
- this timer is also flawless when the device is off, and will go for a full five seconds and then expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough code to make the call.  But two basic problems stand out: you can enable a timer that might already be enabled.  Which doesn't do anything, your timer will expire too soon.  And a more serious problem, you keep adding event handlers.  So it the timer expires then the Tick event handler will run multiple times.

You will need to subscribe the Tick event just once, do so in the constructor of your class.

And you have to make sure that the timer is disabled before you start it.  Do so by setting its Enabled property back to false in the Tick event handler *and* when you received the response.  Presumably the latter is missing.  Raise an InvalidOperationException when it is already enabled it the btnGetData_Click() method since it is a logical error if that's the case.  Or force Enabled = false first if abandoning the attempt to get a response is legal.

Comment: thanks for the information Hans, I'll run a test with the corrected code using your advice, and see how it goes tomorrow, and will post back with the results. :)